# Exclude properties from rendering for all Grails domain classes

Tags: json, rest, grails

The [Grails 2.5.4 docs](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.4/guide/webServices.html) say that it's possible to exclude properties from rendering for an entire group of domain classes.

> There are some default configured renderers and the ability to register or override renderers for a given domain class or even for a collection of domain classes.

However there's no example given in the docs for how to do this. Does anyone know how to exclude properties for all of my domain classes? Specifically I'm trying to get rid of the `class` and `enumType` fields that Grails automatically adds to the response body.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any good way to do this. What I discovered is that if you register an exclusion for a super class, all subclasses also "inherit" that exclusion. So to get rid of four properties for *all* Groovy objects (which cover all domain classes), I added the following bean to **resources.groovy**.

```
groovyObjectJsonRenderer(JsonRenderer, GroovyObject) {
    excludes = ['class', 'declaringClass', 'errors', 'version']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are talking about this, but you can ignore some properties when you `render as JSON`, overriding the **Marshaller** here is the code:

```
static {
    grails.converters.JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(NAMEOFYOURCLASS) {
    return it.properties.findAll {k,v -> k != 'class' && k!='declaringClass'}
    }
}
```

or if you want to create your custom render you can do something like this

```
static {
    grails.converters.JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(NAMEOFYOURCLASS) {
        def lista = [:]
        lista['id'] = it.id
        lista['name'] = it.name
        lista['dateCreated'] = it.date?.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
        return lista
    }
}
```

You can put it where you think its better i actually prefer to put it in the class i'm overriding, because letter i can find it or if some one else it's looking the code, he/she can find it easy.

Comment: This is the right idea, but I don't want to register one marshaller or one renderer for every domain class in my Grails project. From an API perspective I don't think any company that designs any API would want the `class` property included in the response, so I'm amazed there isn't a global, one-liner that gets rid of this extraneous field in response bodies.